Getting Facebook Notifications Using .NET
I am thinking of building a web app using .NET (8, 9, if this matters), which would read Facebook notifications for registered users (not posting/making modifications at this moment).
Where should I start looking? I already have a FB dev account and I created an app there. Is there any working library that can help me build this, or do I need to start from scratch? Anything I should be aware of? And what about up-to-date tutorials?
I understand this is a bit broad, but I really need some pointers.
